# Auto change splash screen after log on

Tags: kde, login, autologin

I know how to change the splash screen, however I would like it to change automatically. Say I have a folder of images and I want each of them appear to be splash screen randomly every time I log on. I use KDE.

Comment: how do you change it now?  Can you not automate this process and then call it when you login?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I change it manually by go to System Settings > Workspace Behavior > Splash Screen. I don't understand your second question.

Comment: So there is some type of menu containing the configuration file that may possibly contain the name of the utility program.

Comment: yeah, do you know what it is?